# How to remove product-category from urls in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to woocommerce and I'm struggling to remove **product-category** from the category url.

I've read the solution provided on [WooCommerce- How to remove product & product-category from urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447175/woocommerce-how-to-remove-product-product-category-from-urls) but I'm not sure if it still works.

Woocommerce shop entry page
https://floridapsychics.org/shop/

A product page, it doesn't show any product-category so it's perfectly fine
https://floridapsychics.org/shop/tarot-cards/dionysus-classic-design-tarot-cards-deck-with-guidebook

If you click on Tarot Cards in the breadcrumb it will lead to
https://floridapsychics.org/product-category/tarot-cards

I want above url to be
https://floridapsychics.org/shop/tarot-cards

How to do it?

Here are my permalink settings

[Permalinks settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qCf8.png)

I tried tweaking permalink settings but none seem to work.

Comment: Try . value in Product category base.

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't work.