# how to remove product category slug but show all the slug category terms and the sub-category woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

so I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447175/woocommerce-how-to-remove-product-product-category-from-urls), and it worked fine. but not with sub-categories.

the first of 2nd sub categories works fine, but if the sub-category more than 2, it return 404. take a look at this :

- I have this breadcrumb, each can be clicked (cause it's a sub-category)
- Like I said, the first of 2nd sub categories can be clicked, but the rest, it returns 404. the first of 2nd is test1 and test2-productcat (home is not count).
- [image]

so far I've tried :

- var_dump the first breadcrumb (test1) and it shows like this :

```
array(2) { ["page"]=> string(0) "" ["name"]=> string(5) "test1" }
```

- var_dump the second breadcrumb (test2-productcat) :

```
array(1) { ["attachment"]=> string(16) "test2-productcat" }
```

- after that it just return 404, like this

```
array(1) { ["error"]=> string(3) "404" }
```

why it behave like this? I mean the first is return page, second return attachment? is it possible to do like I want to achive?

thank you.

EDIT :
if you guys wonder how i manage the categories, I set the categories like this :

- test1 parent category for test2-productcat
- test2-productcat is a child of test1
- test3-product-cat is a child of test2-productcat
- jepitan-pin-rambut is a child of test3-product-cat
- an so on

Anyone? I still can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i find a dolution for this. just use plugin permalink manager for woocommerce. and voila it works relly well.